# iOS Swift - Singleton data persistance

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, singleton

I am developping an application that saves informations about the logged-in user in CoreData and singleton class. After the user log-in, I'm fetching data from coredata and set the variables from the singleton.

My question:

If the app receives memory warning issue, and the data from the singleton will be released, my app will crash. What can I do in this situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a local property named `NSArray *myArray` in singleton's `.m` file where you store all the needed data. All you need to do is to add a method in header file which returns that array if is not `nil`, and in case of `nil` make it reload from storage and return.
Also override `- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning` method and save the data in case of memory warning.
Here is a sample code written in objective-c:

```
//Singleton.h file
- (NSArray *)storedData;

//Singleton.m file
@property NSArray *myArray;
...
- (NSArray *)storedData
{
    if (_myArray == nil)
        _myArray = [self fetchMyArrayFromLocalStorage];

    return _myArray;
}

- (NSArray *)fetchMyArrayFromLocalStorage
{
    //Some code to fetch data from local storage
}

- (void)saveMyArrayToLocalStorage
{
    //Code to save _myArray to local storage
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [self saveMyArrayToLocalStorage];
    _myArray = nil; //Remove array if is needed
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
```

Now you'll always get the data you needed simply by calling method:
`[[mySingleton sharedInstance] storedData]`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So, if the data stored in the singleton is deleted by a memory waning, the only way to have again that data is to fetch local db again.

Answer (score 1):

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
```

Your ViewController would have this method by default, and before your app crash, this method will execute automatically, you should write some code in this method to make sure your data can be saved in device, and then release it.

Comment: Ok, I know that. But in this case, the variables from the singleton will become nil, so I need to fetch again data from coreData, and set variables from singleton again, no?